# In Postfix, how do I measure how much traffic is used by each user or domain?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, logging

In Postfix, how do I measure how much traffic is used by each user or domain?

I can see no "out of the box" means of doing this with vanilla postfix, however, I am sure this is a pretty common need. So how do you solve it?

Bonus info would be to also measure dovecot traffic as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Postfix logs, how about [isoqlog](http://www.enderunix.org/isoqlog/)? It's a bit dusty and old, but generates nice HTML summaries. If you want a command line tool, `pflogsumm` is excellent.

I don't know about Dovecot statistics, I'm more familiar with Cyrus.

Comment: ..and contains some primo PHP exploit opportunities. Please, avoid isoqlog like the proverbial.

Answer (score 1):

How much traffic is generated in what way ? Where ?
On the network, coming in, going out, being processed ?

You can parse the logs to determine how many *messages* are received, sent, etc - the well-known mailgraph webapp is good at that.

For actual message sizes per domain, you may be better off piping the postfix logs to a database, where they can be efficiently processed.