# Postfix: How to monitor no of mails send by a user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Postfix, how do I measure how much traffic is used by each user or domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/343436/in-postfix-how-do-i-measure-how-much-traffic-is-used-by-each-user-or-domain)

Is there any way/tool to monitor total no. of mails send by a mail user. I am already using awstats but no luck it's give report for total mails send in a day or month. I have postfix server on ubuntu 10.04LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use tool called - pflogsumm.
It takes your mail logs and produce very nice summary of all mail received, rejected, sent, delivered and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Put the log entries in a database. And then you can do SUM(), GROUP BY, ORDER BY and whatever you like. There is no built-in in Postfix. If you have millions or billions of log entries per day then you should consider NO-SQL databases for your use-case.